# Is improving existing electric a good idea? Is it allowed?

Tags: rewire, knob-and-tube

I am rewiring a house which has a mix of K&T and older (i.e. non Romex, ungrounded) wiring.  This is taking some time as I can only work on it on the weekends.

As I work, I see problems on circuits I'm not currently working on.  There are quick things I could do to make them better.  For instance, for the K&T there are some hot dead-end legs.  I want to cut them back to the nearest junction, then strip the end and place a Wago lock-nut as a terminator.  Thus, in just a few minutes, I can make something that was really bad into something that is better than it was before...although not up to today's Code.  After I finish my current work, I'll move to the area I figure is next most important to work on, removing everything including my temporary improvement.

Is it better to leave the bad things I find alone until I get the time to fix them properly?  Or is it better to do these temporary improvements?

I'm in Oregon, USA.

Comment: Bad things have a habit of becoming worst things.  If you can safely remove bad things that is good, even if not up to today's code.  Bad things probably should be fix first before not bad things are fix.

Comment: For it being allowed, it depends on your local codes/regulations.  Some places allow you to do everything, other places require a electrician to do anything besides changing a light bulb(think at first draft, electrician was needed for light bulbs).

Comment: Where in the world do you live? That will help with the answers about what you're allowed to do and not allowed to do. Even in the US, where the homeowner is _generally_ allowed to do _most_ things, you're not allowed to do wiring if it's going to be a rental property, so knowing that is important, too.

Comment: Thanks all.  I am in the US, Oregon.  I pulled a permit for the work and mention just 1 circuit that I am working on now.  It is apparently easy to add additional circuits to the permit.  Apparently, even changing receptacles requires a permit although with all the three-pronged, ungrounded receptacles I doubt that a permit was used by previous owners.

Comment: Your question, while certainly valid to you, is vague and subjective. You'll need to ask something more specific here.

Comment: isherwood, fair enough.  I tried several edits with limited success.  I'm looking for fundamental principles to follow when dealing with existing electric.  In electrical, it seems like if you touch it, you have to bring it up to code.  Likely electricians must follow this rule, so therefore, they should leave dangerous conditions as-is unless they are willing to do a complete fix.  My opinion is that making a bad situation better is the correct choice versus leaving it alone.  But I wanted the experience of people who have done more electrical work than I have.